# ComputeLineMetrics in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using computeLineMetrics to calculate the number of lines. Now, I want to know, for example, what is the text of the third line? What should I do ?

Comment: call [getPositionForOffset](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextPainter/getPositionForOffset.html) twice: with left and right  offset of the third line